# Determine gcc-toolchain version in clang++ preprocessor

Tags: c++, gcc, clang++

According to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support), the gcc libstdc++ supports the parallelism TS. In layperson terms and for what's relevant for me that means `#include <execution>` works in g++ 9 and doesn't work in g++ 8 or before. In my source code I can handle this with

```cpp
#if ( defined( __GNUC__ ) && __GNUC__ > 8 )
#  define can_use_std_execution
#  include <execution>
#endif
```

For my clang++ builds, the availability of `<execution>` depends on the `--gcc-toolchain` that I use. So instead of checking the `__clang_major__`, I'd like to check the gcc libstdc++ version in the preprocessor.

As far as I see [in this compiler-explorer example](https://godbolt.org/z/oV4xGD), `__GNUC__` is defined in clang but the compilation command is

```
-g -o /tmp/compiler-explorer-compiler120120-1672-4ffux6.smufm/output.s -mllvm --x86-asm-syntax=intel -S --gcc-toolchain=/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-8.3.0 -fcolor-diagnostics -fno-crash-diagnostics /tmp/compiler-explorer-compiler120120-1672-4ffux6.smufm/example.cpp
```

i.e. the gcc toolchain is from gcc 8.3.0, but the value of `__GNUC__` is 4.

What's a good way to query the gcc toolchain version in the preprocessor with clang? Ideally a way that checks the libstdc++ version in a way that's compatible for g++ and clang++ such that I don't have write a spaghetti if that checks the compiler first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grepping for `^#.*define.*9` in the compiler headers of gcc 9 it seems that

```cpp
#include <bits/c++config.h>
#if _GLIBCXX_RELEASE > 8
#  include <execution>
#endif
```

can do the job. From [this conformance view](https://godbolt.org/z/a9ZE_L) this variable was introduced with the toolchain of gcc 7.